# PHP - count specific array values, multiple values

Tags: php, arrays, count

How do you count the occurrence of more than one value in an array?

I found below on stackoverflow,

```
$array = array("Kyle","Ben","Sue","Phil","Ben","Mary","Sue","Ben");
$counts = array_count_values($array);
echo $counts['Ben'];
```

I have used this, but I can't get it to work and there must be a more elegant way,

```
$array = array("Kyle","Ben","Sue","Phil","Ben","Mary","Sue","Mary","Ben");
$counts = array_count_values($array);
$1 = $counts['Ben'];
$2 = $counts['Phil'];
$3 = $counts['Mary'];
echo $1+$2+$3;
```

Comment: It appears to me the only thing amiss with this code is that you cannot have numeric variable names. I.e. `$1` is an invalid variable name. `$name1` works fine.

Comment: echo $counts['Ben']+$counts['Phil']+$counts['Mary'];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// change your code to this
$array = array("Kyle","Ben","Sue","Phil","Ben","Mary","Sue","Mary","Ben");
$counts = array_count_values($array);
$one = $counts['Ben']; // 3
$two = $counts['Phil']; // 1
$three = $counts['Mary']; // 2
echo $one + $two + $three; // 6

// because of this :)
$var = 'Bob';
$Var = 'Joe';
echo "$var, $Var";      // outputs "Bob, Joe"
$4site = 'not yet';     // invalid; starts with a number <-- your case
$_4site = 'not yet';    // valid; starts with an underscore
$täyte = 'mansikka';    // valid; 'ä' is (Extended) ASCII 228.
$bar = &$foo;           // This is a valid assignment.
$bar = &(24 * 7);       // Invalid; references an unnamed expression.
```

More on [PHP variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php)

Comment: `echo $counts['Ben']+$counts['Phil']+$counts['Mary'];` Worked. I thought there might be a solution like `echo $counts['Ben'+'Phil'+'Mary'];` but obviously not.

Answer (score 0):

if you want count occurance without using array_count_values() functions then use this code

```
    $array = array("Kyle","Ben","Sue","Phil","Ben","Mary","Sue","Ben");

$len = sizeof($array);

$i = 0;
$occurance = 0;

while( $i < $len )

{

    if($array[$i] == 'Ben')
    {
        $occurance++;
    }

    $i++;
}

echo 'number of occurance of Ben ='.$occurance;
```